# Figuring out how a Motorola 68K test case with ADD.b and Full Extension Word passes

Tags: motorola

I'm developing a Motorola 68000 emulator, and I have found a million test cases to run, and currently I'm stuck with the first test with (d8, AX, Xn) addressing.

Here's the test case. Notice that prefetch values are provided as two words, and also only one instruction is tested. The problem is basically that I cannot even manually figure out how 13367077 is calculated. Whatever it is, I'm sure it's masked with 24-bits, and I cannot figure out the unmasked value.

```
d133 [ADD.b D0, (d8, A3, Xn)] 1
Len = 18

==== Initial ====
D0 = 2308435391     0x8997edbf  0b10001001 10010111 11101101 10111111 
D1 = 1060694383     0x3f38e96f  0b00111111 00111000 11101001 01101111 
D2 = 144798559      0x8a1735f   0b00001000 10100001 01110011 01011111 
D3 = 1114670029     0x427083cd  0b01000010 01110000 10000011 11001101 
D4 = 3546817942     0xd3682596  0b11010011 01101000 00100101 10010110 
D5 = 3017016069     0xb3d40305  0b10110011 11010100 00000011 00000101 
D6 = 157945861      0x96a1005   0b00001001 01101010 00010000 00000101 
D7 = 3531664314     0xd280ebba  0b11010010 10000000 11101011 10111010 
A0 = 1707790453     0x65cad075  0b01100101 11001010 11010000 01110101 
A1 = 3858677903     0xe5fec08f  0b11100101 11111110 11000000 10001111 
A2 = 3797006336     0xe251b800  0b11100010 01010001 10111000 00000000 
A3 = 2874897130     0xab5b72ea  0b10101011 01011011 01110010 11101010 
A4 = 3126142618     0xba55269a  0b10111010 01010101 00100110 10011010 
A5 = 271034980      0x1027aa64  0b00010000 00100111 10101010 01100100 
A6 = 2663102061     0x9ebbb66d  0b10011110 10111011 10110110 01101101 
SSP = 2048      0x800   0b00000000000000000000100000000000
USP = 2048      0x800   0b00000000000000000000100000000000
PC = 3072       0xc00   0b00000000000000000000110000000000
SR = 9993       0x2709  0b00000000000000000010011100001001
Prefetch: 53555, 15214  0x3B6E      0b00111011 01101110
[MEMORY]
3079 = 160  A0  41206
3078 = 246  F6  
13367077 = 228  E4
3077 = 181  B5
3076 = 237  ED  46573   87779   175558

==== Final ====
D0 = 2308435391     0x8997edbf  0b10001001 10010111 11101101 10111111 
D1 = 1060694383     0x3f38e96f  0b00111111 00111000 11101001 01101111 
D2 = 144798559      0x8a1735f   0b00001000 10100001 01110011 01011111 
D3 = 1114670029     0x427083cd  0b01000010 01110000 10000011 11001101 
D4 = 3546817942     0xd3682596  0b11010011 01101000 00100101 10010110 
D5 = 3017016069     0xb3d40305  0b10110011 11010100 00000011 00000101 
D6 = 157945861      0x96a1005   0b00001001 01101010 00010000 00000101 
D7 = 3531664314     0xd280ebba  0b11010010 10000000 11101011 10111010 
A0 = 1707790453     0x65cad075  0b01100101 11001010 11010000 01110101 
A1 = 3858677903     0xe5fec08f  0b11100101 11111110 11000000 10001111 
A2 = 3797006336     0xe251b800  0b11100010 01010001 10111000 00000000 
A3 = 2874897130     0xab5b72ea  0b10101011 01011011 01110010 11101010 
A4 = 3126142618     0xba55269a  0b10111010 01010101 00100110 10011010 
A5 = 271034980      0x1027aa64  0b00010000 00100111 10101010 01100100 
A6 = 2663102061     0x9ebbb66d  0b10011110 10111011 10110110 01101101 
SSP = 2048      0x800   0b00000000000000000000100000000000
USP = 2048      0x800   0b00000000000000000000100000000000
PC = 3076       0xc04   0b00000000000000000000110000000100
SR = 10009      0x2719  0b00000000000000000010011100011001
Prefetch: 60853, 63136
[MEMORY]
3079 = 160
3078 = 246
13367077 [0xCBF725] = 163
3077 = 181
3076 = 237
```

Judging by the eighth bit of the second prefetch value (15214), we have a full-extension word to deal with. For some reason, I/IS bits map to a reserved combination! And when I read the next long word (judging by index size), and add all of that up, I can't get the result.

Here's the description of extension words from the documentation:
[image]

P.S. The tests are taken from https://github.com/TomHarte/ProcessorTests/tree/main/680x0/68000/v1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was surprised that nobody pointed this out, but Motorola 68000 doesn't support Full Extension Words and ignores the bits 8-10; therefore it's only supported by other models of 68K family. So the word should be masked out first and then the test passes.